# Pika connection lost Error: pika.exceptions.StreamLostError: Stream connection lost: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, mysql-python, pika

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "download_image_from_queue.py", line 44, in

```
channel.start_consuming()
```

File "/home/justdial/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1866, in start_consuming

```
self._process_data_events(time_limit=None)
```

File "/home/justdial/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 2027, in _process_data_events

```
self.connection.process_data_events(time_limit=time_limit)
```

File "/home/justdial/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 825, in process_data_events

```
self._flush_output(common_terminator)
```

File "/home/justdial/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 522, in _flush_output

```
raise self._closed_result.value.error

pika.exceptions.StreamLostError: Stream connection lost: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'
```

file "download_image_from_queue.py":

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):

    default_flag = True

    try:
        data = json.loads(body.decode("utf-8"))['DATA']

        url = data['url']
        dest_name = data['dest_name']

        default_flag = False
    except:
        print ("\n INCORRECT DATA FORMAT INSERTED INTO THE QUEUE... \n")
        pass

    if default_flag == False:
        os.system("cd /home/images_pred/ && wget -L --timeout=3 --tries=2 {} -O {}".format(url, dest_name))

    print ('\n Waiting for the queue to be filled...       PRESS CTRL+C TO STOP \n')


credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('abcd', 'BCD')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('0.0.0.1', 5672, '/', credentials )


connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
channel = connection.channel()
#channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count = 1)

channel.basic_consume(queue = 'IMG_DOWNLOAD', auto_ack = False, on_message_callback = callback)
#channel.basic_ack()

print ('\n Waiting for the queue to be filled...       PRESS CTRL+C TO STOP \n')

channel.start_consuming()
```

once it start consuming, it starts download but sooner it gives this error "pika.exceptions.StreamLostError: Stream connection lost: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')"

can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Please read [this](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/comparing_publishing_sync_async.html) and [this](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/asynchronous_consumer_example.html)

Answer (score 1):

Till the time the job gets processed and your process comes back to send an ACK, there are many heartbeats missed, and thus the connection gone.

**Ideal Solution (Recommended)**

Use threading and run your code in thread. Check a sample here:

https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/1.0.1/examples/basic_consumer_threaded.py

**Quick Workaround** [Not Recommended]

Disable heartbeats.

How to disable heartbeats? --> Pass **heartbeat=0** while creating connection.

```
pika.ConnectionParameters(
   host=RABBIT_MQ_HOST, credentials=CREDENTIALS, heartbeat=0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using different **connection_attempts** parameters while setting up the connection. The default value for connection_attempts is 1. For more information look at the below link.
https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/parameters.html